# Database Imported Rows but No of Rows Are Not Equal to Exported Database's Rows

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have exported a database from PhpMyAdmin which contains 107 tables and 357,005 rows.

**Problem:**
When I import the database, it has 107 tables but rows are only 293,213.
I have tried again exporting and then again importing several times but no luck. Sometimes an error is prompted which is shown in the picture below.

**Error:**

[image]

**Sometimes this error appears:**
[image]

Please help, how can I fix imported database to have exactly the number of rows that are in exported (main) database?

Comment: Did you try searching for the error Access denied on google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the mysql documentation, For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. So, Phpmyadmin Tool picks the row count from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The table_rows which phpmyadmin picks which is never accurate for Innodb.

To find the exact row count, we need

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 'table_name';
```

Take a table where you see the difference and run this command to check the exact count.

Comment: Great, Thanks for explanation but I have 107 tables, it would take forever for me to know row count of each table and then match it with the online database's tables. Do you have any shorter idea.

Comment: @ZaeemJaved, Unfortunately, This is one of the restrictions of InnoDB. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-tables-table.html) for more info.  You could always use a `SELECT count(*) FROM 'table_name';`.  You can write some shell script or simple program with loop to get all the table rows count.